# <script> tag position before <html> tag

Tags: html, validation, scripting, tags

Can a `<script>` tag between `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<html>` be valid?

The reason I ask is I found the code I've described above. Can it be valid under any circumstances?

Comment: It works (in many cases afaik) but it's not valid and should not be done.

Comment: For what reason would you do it anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `<html>` is the root (or document) element of an HTML document; it must be the only root-level element in an HTML document (it cannot have any siblings). Further, HTML can only contain `<head>` and `<body>` (specifically one of each), meaning that any other tags (e.g. `<script>` must be descendants of `<head>` or `<body>`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.
If you want check. Use this validator:
http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options